# Details for the extension $1 \to F_2 \to \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to 1$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, exact-sequence

We have the group extension $1 \to F_2 \to \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to 1$, where $F_2$ is the free group on two elements $a$ and $b$. Do we know the explicit expression of

- the corresponding action $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \to \text{Aut}(F_2)$, and
- the corresponding 2-cocycle $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to F_2$ ?

Also, how can one express a matrix $M \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ as a pair $(x,p)$, with $x \in F_2$, $p \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ ? (I know that $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ will be sent to $(a,0)$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ to $(b,0)$ since they are generators of the commutator subgroup, but I'm stuck in the general case)

Any details or references is appreciated.

Comment: With $G = SL(2,Z)$, what are your generators of $[G,G]$, the image of your map from the free group  ? (the other map is $G \to G/[G,G] \cong Z_{12}$)

Comment: The question only makes sense if $a,b$ are explicitly described, so you should write from the beginning that $a,b$ are defined by these given matrices. Also "the corresponding action" is not well-defined, not defined at all: in an exact sequence one can only naturally define a map from the quotient to Out of the kernel (a map to Aut of the kernel arises when a splitting is given, but in this case there's no splitting at all). A 2-cocycle also depends of a set-wise splitting (which exists, but should be given). If you don't prescribe the set-wise splittng, you only define a 2-cohomology class.

Comment: I agree with you, the set-wise splitting has to be given, this was the second part of my question, on which I'm stuck too. I choose to inject the generators of the free group into the two matrices given above, and there also is a known homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ which gives $p$, but I don't know about the general case. In the end, I just need the group law to check some calculations.

Comment: @reuns I think the answer to your question is in my original post, the two generators of the free group are sent to the two given matrices in $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}_{12})$